# gitflow, tags an versions numbers

Tags: git, version

I need two thing for a work project: a clear branching model, and a way to accurately track the origin of my binaries.

I want to follow the gitflow branching model, which seems to perfectly suits my need.

For the origin of the binaries, I use `git describe --dirty` in my makefiles, to generate a string which is stored in my binaries. That way, running any executable with the --version option tells me precisely where it comes from.

Everything seemed to work fine until it try to use both of these:
For the binaries built from master, it works perfectly. I have a clean version number, which is the name of the last tag.
However, when I compile from another branch, there is no tag in the ancestors, so no useful string produced by `git describe`...

I know there is a --always option which output the SHA-1 if no tag is found, but what I really want is something like "v1.3.2-15-3b7bf9f", instead of "3b7bf9f".

How can I make the tag on master accessible from all the other branches? I thought about merging master into develop after every tag pushed on master, but I'm not really sure it's safe...

Am I missing something, or are gitflow and `git describe` sort of "incompatible"?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`git describe` can't do this, because the commit you're on has nothing to do with the tags on `master`. Except for the merges from that branch to master.

First, you'll need to find the commit that is the merge base from the current branch and master:

```
$ export mergebase=`git merge-base HEAD master`
```

This will save on `mergebase` the commit we want (using bash).

Next, you'll get the merge commit on master (using `git rev-list`) and then you can get
the antecessor tag from the merge commit:

`$ export tag=git rev-list --merges --max-count=1 ${mergebase}..master | xargs git describe --tags --abbrev=0`

Finding the commit hash of HEAD:

```
$ export commit=`git rev-parse HEAD`
```

And the latest equivalent tag on master with the commit you are in:

```
$ echo "${tag}-${commit}"
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to do what I want. Your solution find the latest merge in master, not the last from the commit where I stand.
Also, the final output is the `git describe` of the tag found, not of the current state.

Comment: The solution I proposed is only to find the latest tag on master before the latest merge on master from the branch you are in. I can't think another way to get the tag. With the tag, you can format the it to add the hash of the current commit.